# Reverse engineering and buffer overflows: zero to hero

Tags: buffer-overflow, reverse-engineering, assembly

When I do CTFs, I can usually cope well with and understanding everything pretty much apart from buffer overflows, binary exploitation and reverse engineering

Almost to the point that I would consider myself having zero knowledge at all. I grasp the concept at the very most basic of levels and by that I mean I can operate a mouse and keyboard

Is there anywhere that takes you from zero to hero? I'm currently doing CTFs on https://0x0539.net/ and have done most of them apart from reverse engineering ones.

https://liveoverflow.com/ is a decent start I believe *but* was wondering where there was a book, an online resource that as I say, could take me from zero to hero

I understand there's a "stack" and "memory" and "assembly language" and then after that... nothing.

Specifically - I would like to get to a point where I come across a related challenge in a CTF and at least know where to start, where to go and how to complete it

Thanks

Comment: Have you read the Wikipedia article about [Buffer Overflows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow)? If so, what exactly is it that you don't understand? Your question is too broad as it is, so I am trying to help you focus it a bit more

Comment: How to utilise this knowledge in CTFs basically. Using IDA, R2, GDB etc

Comment: Then please show a specific challenge you struggle with.

Comment: All of them on https://0x0539.net but specifically https://0x0539.net/play/fangorn > "Rock Paper Scissors" and also "Go Ahead Crack Me". Rock paper Scissors, for example, takes an input where you give it a length of your name, second input is your name, it then prints your name and you play the game (where you lose). If you put in a value of 1 and put name as Jo, it outputs Jo. If you put length in as -1 and 23 characters as your name, it outputs all 23....

Comment: Try the "Software Security" course from Michael Hicks / Maryland University on Coursera. It's got plenty on C-language-level security and the stack, well explained. Whatever you do **do not** spend your time on the Hardware Security course, in my opinion it was abysmally bad with the Usable Security being just "fair". Cryptography was fine, close to Cryptography I from Stanford really - slightly different take.

Answer (score 2):

I think the standard, at least back in the 90's was *"Smashing the stack for fun and profit"* from [phrack magazine](http://phrack.org/issues/49/14.html).